# How to compile Neofetch (from git) in arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, make, packaging, pkgbuild, makepkg

I know the latest  Neofetch is available in the official arch repository but I want to build it from the git clone.
Since it doesn't have the PKGBUILD so makepkg is out of question and the global step ( make install) doesn't do anything. I have read that Yaourt compiles it with makepkg.
But how to do that without any AUR helper?

Answer (score 1):

You could get the [neofetch git AUR package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/neofetch-git/), which is called `neofetch-git`. You can install it with an AUR helper, or if you want to build manually:
`git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/neofetch-git.git
cd neofetch-git
makepkg -si`

Or, you can [build directly from git](https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/wiki/Installation):
`git clone https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch.git
cd neofetch
make && sudo make install`